# Version Control Client Server Applications

Tags: version-control, client-server, version, cvs, repository

I am looking at some client server cvs applications to be used corporately. I would like if i can get some feed back to support my research in terms of experience with the best OPEN SOURCE applications in this field. Basically I am looking for an application that can manage and work with several repositories but maintain one central repository for source code.

Also the application must be able to allow the setting of security access on files and folders and support command line access. I would like to know based in your experiences working with these applications which ones you would rate highly in terms of the features mentioned.

Comment: Must we read `cvs` tag as `vcs`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption of <kbd>vcs</kbd> tag:

- Subversion as pure CVCS system, with caution: One repo, multiply clients (Working Copies). Inter-repositories communications are *worse than terrible*
- DVCS, which can be used in mixed or pseudo-CVCS mode: Mercurial. With caution (TBT by Mercurial guru): file and dir access rights missing in core, maybe can be implemented in hooks. Due to monolithic nature of repo, minimal object for ACL is branch (extension needed)

**Short CheetList**

```
Feature                                                     Subversion       Mercurial

manage and work with several repositories                    + (client)           +

maintain one central repository for source code                  +                +

allow the setting of security access on files and folders     Folders             -

support command line access                                      +                +
```

---

```
BonusPack    

Cross-platform                                                   +                +

IDE-integration                                                  +                +

GUI-clients                                                      +                +
```